# How to increase Grease Pencil dot density?

Tags: grease-pencil

I am using a textured brush [from blender.](https://cloud.blender.org/p/gallery/5f235cc297f8815e74ffb90b) If I stay zoomed in, the dot density is fine; however upon zooming out it no longer forms a cohesive line.

[image]

Past solutions on here have simply said to set the line type to line instead of dots. However, this makes it so that it looks completely different.

[image]

Is there any way to increase the density of the dots?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the stroke menu (at the top of the 3D viewport when in grease pencil mode) you have two options to change the stroke density.

The simplest is to turn down the 'simplify value' but you can also increase 'subdivision steps' if turning down simplify lags when drawing.

[image: blender's stroke menu (at the top of the 3D viewport when in grease pencil mode)]